# ImportError: cannot import name 'Covid' from partially initialized module 'covid'?

Tags: python

What's the problem? this is all of the code which is I want to run, but this error makes it unusable!

```
from covid import Covid

covid = Covid()
covid.get_data()
```

Comment: I'm guessing the name of your file is `covid.py`. Why are you trying to import from the file you are running?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: yes dear, I was used, but now when I change the File name, the issue is solved. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/covid/), it seems to work fine.

```py
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from covid import Covid
>>>
>>> covid = Covid()
>>> covid.get_data()
[...]
```

Have you tried updating? If so, have you tried using any other module?

Also, make sure you're not running a file structure like

```
project
| covid
| | your-file.py
```

if you're running `from covid import Covid` from `your-file.py`, it will fail, since it's trying to import from the `covid` directory your-file.py is in.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the file name which is `covid.py`, so after that everything is working correctly.